# BIOS Setup is showing Gliches in Half Screen in ASUS TUF F15 2021

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, cpu, bios

My laptop with BIOS Screen with half screen flickering or not visible:
[image: BIOS Screen Screenshot with half screen flickering or not visible]:

> 1. BIOS American Megatrends Inc.
> 2. BIOS Version: FX506LH. 310
> 3. 26/11/2021 (Bought on this date)
> 4. RAM: DDR4 16 GB
> 5. Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
> 6. Processor: Intel Core i5 10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz

I am experiencing no issues with my system while using Windows 11. However, I am encountering difficulties specifically when accessing the BIOS screen. Please refer to the attached image for further clarification regarding the problem I am facing with the BIOS Setup Utility.

Comment: Possibly, BIOS does not have drivers needed for that monitor at its current settings, though Windows does. Can you manually adjust the monitor for lower resolution and refresh rate?

Comment: Your CPU includes Intel UHD Graphics, which is the one that is used for BIOS display. Windows itself might prefer the GTX 1650 in many cases. What model is the monitor?

Comment: Dr Moishe Pippik How can I do it for BIOS I have adjusted my laptop for lower resolution & refresh rate?

Comment: @harrymc How can I find it? Actually it is a laptop Asus TUF F15 2021

Comment: This is the built-in screen so the problem is likely hardware. Checking all connections between the display adapter and screen would be a start. Professional help might be useful.